# Use the values of my csv file as variables in Python to create a customizable "object"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, class

I want to use the values of this csv file to create a custom command in GAM(Google Workspace)(I would use the GAM command using import os)

```
Robert.Samson,50,false,teacher
Sam.Robertson,20,swimming,bartender
David.Bufi,100,biking,false
Med.Sevia,70,false,lawyer
```

Example of the command Robert: `gam queries "\"directmanager='testuser@domain.com' issuspended=false, name='test'\"" print users`

So as you can see my idea is to recreate that command for example but using the values of the csv and do it for a lot of users.
Have in mind that there are some parts of the command will be there by default as directmanager or issuspended.

Code I have so far:

```
import csv

my_list = []
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        my_list.append({'name': row[0], 'age': int(row[1]), 
                        'hobbies': row[2], 'profession': row[3]})
print(my_list)
```

Something to have in mind is that I don't want to take the values that are false in the csv, for the use Robert I don't want to take his hobbies because is false.

Examples:

```
gam queries "\"directmanager='testuser@domain.com' issuspended=false name='Robert.Samson' age='50' profession='teacher'\"" print users

gam queries "\"directmanager='testuser@domain.com' issuspended=false, name='Sam.Robertson' age='20' hobbies=swimming profession='bartender' \"" print users
```

I don't know what is the best approach to do this I don't have much experienced with classes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your row up in a more piecemeal manner:

```
for row in reader:
    row_dict = {
        'name': row[0],
        'age': int(row[1],
        'profession': row[3]
    }

    if row[2]:
        row_dict['hobbies'] = row[2]

    my_list.append(row_dict)
```